# Azure DevOps: Copying files to az fileshare very slow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-pipelines

When I mount an Azure Fileshare from my Azure DevOps pipeline and copy files to the file share via robocopy, this is with 80 Megabytes per minute (12 MBit/s) very slow:

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       456       456       249         0         0         0
   Files :      4122      4122         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   2.809 g   2.809 g         0         0         0         0
   Times :  18:36:49   0:35:04                       0:00:00   0:01:10
   Ended : Wednesday, January 29, 2020 11:52:31 PM
```

I use a `StorageV2` account. Azure DevOps and the storage account are in different regions. This is the robocopy command I use:

```
robocopy ..\my_directory z:\my_directory /E /NS /NC /NP /XD .git /MT:32 /W:5
```

... and this is how I have mounted the azure fileshare inside the pipeline:

```
New-PSDrive -Name $(storage.drive) -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$(storage.unc)" -Persist
```

Is this normal? How can I make it significantly faster?

Comment: Hi friend, have you tried to run that robocopy command locally? Is it also slow like using Devops pipeline ?

Comment: Good question! - I have tried it now, and it took one minute and one second to copy the same amount of files "locally" within the Microsoft Azure Cloud Agent (instead of 35:04 minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got lightning fast (1 minute, 30 seconds) when I moved the azure fileshare to the same region as the Azure DevOps Pipeline.

The region of Azure DevOps is displayed in the organizational settings of Azure Devops.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members to search this useful information more easily, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, instead of using robocopy we recommend using AzCopy v10.4 or later. Unlike robocopy, it's optimized for transferring over long distances to cloud storage.

(We also have various fuller-featured data transfer tools, but for a user experience directly comparable to robocopy, but with faster speed, AzCopy is the way to go).

Comment: Do you maybe know the answer for this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096837/azure-pipeline-custom-task-with-an-unknown-number-of-inputs